# Как повторить функцию shuffle n раз

Tags: python, функции, циклы, shuffle

Есть переменная `n` - столько раз должна повториться функция и так же есть переменная `а` - что должно перемешаться

Как мне сделать так, чтобы переменная `а` перемешалась, предположим, 300 раз?

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на вопрос:  `"как мне сделать так, чтобы переменная а перемешалась, предположим, 300 раз?"`

Во-первых, разумеется переменную перемешать нельзя. Перемешать можно некоторую коллекцию -  например, список.

Во-вторых, что-бы перемешать один и тот-же список 300 раз надо функцию перемешивания поместить в цикл и выполнить 300 итераций этого списка.

И вот теперь главный вопрос - а зачем список перемешивать 300 раз? Чего вы хотите добиться? При том, что хоть 3, хоть 300, хоть 30К раз последовательно перемешивая список "лучше" он не перемешается.